# Can Docker images be "built" ("compiled") to not require Docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, 12factor

I have a very small amount of experience with Docker for experimentation and development, and zero experience with Docker when it comes to staging and deployment - so forgive anything that sounds naive.

### The main question

Suppose I have a Docker image (or even a `docker-compose.yml` file consisting of several images and services) which, when run, sets up the environment for my app and runs my app - allowing for connections on a publicly open port and responding to requests.

In order to run this image in production (and therefore in order to run my app in production) the production server must have Docker installed. This feels like a violation of [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) design. Particularly when you consider the [Port Binding](https://12factor.net/port-binding) tenet:

> The twelve-factor app is completely self-contained

Just as an app should not rely on Apache or nginx to be installed, should an app also not rely on Docker to be installed?

This led me to wonder if there were a way to "package", "build", or otherwise "compile" the Docker runtime and the image into an executable binary. Something that could be deployed to **any** server and run as a single process without the need to install Docker first.

**Now, it's possible I'm just thinking about this entirely wrong. For that reason, I've detailed the specifics of the concerns and issues I'm having below**

### What brought this up

I have a web application project that I have previously been developing using [Cloud9](https://c9.io). When I push this project to production, I manually log into the production server via SSH and perform `git pull`, `composer update`, `npm install`, and `gulp`. I bit of a hassle, but for the **very** small scale I'm working at this has been sufficient and it's a ***hell*** of a lot better than uploading all of my dependencies via FTP.

I've occasionally run into challenges with external dependencies, however. Something works fine in development, then when I push it to production I realize the production server has an out-dated version of MySQL. Or the version of pngquant installed on the production server has a bug. Or the nginx config on the server doesn't match the nginx config in development exactly and it's causing some edge case when routing malformed requests.

All of these problems hit at once today when I tried to load up my project in [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/) instead of Cloud9. I had to ensure:

- The PHP version was update
- NodeJS was updated
- NPM was updated
- cURL was installed
- All of the required PHP extensions were installed
- Several GNU libraries were installed
- etc

I spent **hours** trying to get this code running -- and it's code ***I*** wrote

Having all of these problems reminded me of [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) design. So I hopped over to the website and did some thinking to figure out what I was doing wrong.

**Note:** I don't just develop solo and then deploy to production directly. I actually have this project set up in BitBucket, I use a ticketing system to track changes, a branch is created per ticket, and branches are checked out in a staging environment before being merged into master. So I've created a pretty robust system to managing changes to avoid bugs from slipping into production and to allow for agile development. However when it comes to checking out a branch in staging ***or*** production it's the same manual crap: `git pull`, `composer update`, `npm install`, `gulp`.

### What I like about Docker

The ability to define my working environment in a source-controlled config file would eliminate the bulk of my issues. Never again would I need to ensure PHP was up to date, ensure NodeJS was up to date, ensure cURL was installed, etc. If the Docker image has all of the dependencies, then it will still have those dependencies when deployed in staging or production. Consistency of environment between all stages of development would make my life a **lot** easier.

Also, I haven't yet played around with **anything** this advanced, but I'm to understand that it's easy with Docker to set up automated deployment. If I could click on a branch in BitBucket then click "send to staging" and a minute later have it deployed and ready to test -- that would save me hours of time each week. If I could similarly have code automatically deployed to production when it was merged to master, that would not only save me time but would avoid the risk of finished features languishing in BitBucket and never getting in front of a client.

Finally, and this may eventually be a moot point, I'm to understand that Docker makes green/blue deployment ***much*** easier. Currently when I push a new change to production the production server goes offline briefly. Usually only for 15-20 seconds, but once it was an entire hour. During this 15-20 seconds window I'm running `composer update`, `npm install`, and `gulp`. The former two commands usually don't need to do anything (since my dependencies don't change often) and `gulp` usually completes within 15 seconds. However when dependencies ***do*** change or when there are larger issues (like needing to upgrade MySQL) the site can go down for an entire hour. If I could slowly and calmly deploy to a secondary production server then flip the switch in milliseconds when I verified it was working correctly, this would mean less down time and more happy customers.

Of course the last one may be a moot point because I'm currently not utilizing a "build" step (another part of the twelve-factor app), and all of these steps should be part of the "build" phase -- not the "deploy" phase.

### What I don't like about Docker

It's **yet one more tool to learn**. In order to understand and develop for my app you already need to understand:

- PHP
- Composer
- Symfony
- Laravel
- NodeJS
- NPM
- Gulp
- Bootstrap
- VueJS
- (probably many other things I can't think of right now)

Adding "Docker" to that list just means this project gets that much harder to train someone on if I were to ever hand it off to another developer. I want **fewer** dependencies, not more.

Also, Docker doesn't come default with any operating system that I'm aware of. So it's not like cURL where, while it's technically a third-party dependency, you can generally expect people have it. Instead it's a whole beast that has to be installed separately.

The former issue I can't really circumvent. If I choose to use Docker, it means adding one more tool to my toolbox for this app. However the latter issue could be avoided if Docker images can somehow be compiled to stand-alone binaries.

Comment: i don't think it's possible to convert docker images to binaries, but at some point it has to rely on apache or nginx in order to serve the content, otherwise what's the point. and btw it's easy to learn

Comment: Actually a web application does **not** need to rely on Apache or nginx to serve content. All Apache and nginx do is parse HTTP requests and automatically handle some error cases for you. If your app is capable of interpreting HTTP requests then your app can serve as its own HTTP server (binding directly to port 80). This is how many NodeJS web apps work. Apache and nginx are then used as a proxy layer for load balancing and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Docker images do indeed require docker installed on the machine, but it's a much smaller issue then having all the other dependencies you mentioned set up.

While it's probably possible to create some kind of self contained docker image, it would probably be less portable then docker images, as the binary will be os dependent.

also consider that if you use a cloud provider, they provide the ability to deploy docker images "directly on the cloud" - that is, you don't have to manage the underlying servers

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you can run containers from docker images without docker. Docker images are a well known format. See https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec for more details on this spec. There are multiple implementations of the runtime for OCI images. Docker itself doesn't actually run containers, that task has been outsourced to containerd.

However, images ship with a filesystem (also referred to as a bunch of tar files), but containers also expect namespaces to isolate the application. You need some kind of runtime to implement this. Containers are not just a method to package applications, but also a method to run them in isolation, and trying to pull these apart will be more work and create an even bigger thing to learn than docker itself.

Comment: I'm actually a bit torn on which of the two answers that showed up today I should accept. This answer provides more technical detail and actually explains how I could theoretically accomplish what I want (if I find a library that can can serve as a container runtime then I could easily compile it to a stand-alone executable). That said, @OphirYoktan's answer is likely considered better practice as he points out both that a single dependency (Docker) is better than 40 dependencies, and that much like how a JVM allows for build-once-deploy-anywhere, so does Docker.